# Why my for each don't show anything?

Tags: java, jsp, vraptor

I've tried to change the import, but the problem persists

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
```

That foreach

```
<div style="background-color: red; color: white">
<c:forEach var="error" items="${error}">
    ${error.category} - ${error.message}<br />
</c:forEach>
</div>
```

..

and that

```
<table>
  <c:forEach var="apartamento" items="${apartamentos}">
   <tr>
     <td><c:out value="${apartamento.numero}"/></td>   
     <td><c:out value="${apartamento.ocupacao}"/></td> 
     <td><c:out value="${apartamento.quartos}"/></td> 
   </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

The Controller

```
public ApartamentoController(Result result, Validator validator) {

    this.result = result;
    this.validator = validator;
}

public void acessar(List<Apartamento> apartamentos) {
    if(apartamentos == null){
        apartamentos = HibernateUtil.buscar(new Apartamento());
    }
    result.include("apartamentos", apartamentos);
}
```

Pesquisar like Search

```
public void pesquisar(int pesquisa){
    Apartamento apartFiltro = new Apartamento();
    apartFiltro.setNumero(pesquisa);
    List<Apartamento> apartamentos = HibernateUtil.buscar(apartFiltro);
    result.redirectTo(this).acessar(apartamentos);
}
```

Salvar like Save

```
public void salvar(Apartamento apartamento) {
    //pesquisar para arrumar o validator
    if(apartamento.getNumero() == 0){
        validator.add(new ValidationMessage("O número deve ser     preenchido ou diferente de zero!", "error"));
        validator.onErrorRedirectTo(this).acessar(null);
    }
    HibernateUtil.salvar(apartamento);
    result.redirectTo(this).acessar(null);
}

}
```

..................................................

Comment: `forEach` itself looks correct. Can you show related controller's code?

Comment: This should show the list with "Apartments" from mySql Server db